# Bar chart with many bars

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I'm trying to create a bar chart with a lot of information and the final result I get is really messy. Is there any way to make it look something like in the picture? I don't want to use one image from excel as my other graphs are made in latex
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots,filecontents} 
\pgfplotsset{width=14cm,compat=1.9}
\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&]{
    Category&2007&2008&2009&2010&2011&2012&2013&2014&2015 \\
        CS  & 29 & 22   & 32   & 30   & 27  & 19 & 22 & 11 & 13 \\
        CRO & 20 & 11   & 14   & 23   & 17  & 14 & 9  & 9  & 8 \\
        NCO & 23 & 20   & 28   & 35   & 35  & 19 & 24 & 14 & 19 \\
        Ph  & 13 & 23   & 10   & 16   & 14  & 14 & 7  & 10 & 10 \\
        IS  & 52 & 32   & 38   & 34   & 40  & 28 & 34 & 22 & 29 \\
        L   & 8  & 21   & 11   & 14   & 6   & 6  & 10 & 10 & 8 \\
        NUK & 4  & 7    & 9    & 9    & 10  & 18 & 19 & 19 & 15\\
}\mydata


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ybar,
symbolic x coords={CS,CRO,NCO,Ph,IS,L,NUK},
xtick=data,
]
\addplot table[x=Category,y=2007]{\mydata};
\addplot table[x=Category,y=2008]{\mydata};
\addplot table[x=Category,y=2009]{\mydata};
\addplot table[x=Category,y=2010]{\mydata};
\addplot table[x=Category,y=2011]{\mydata};
\addplot table[x=Category,y=2012]{\mydata};
\addplot table[x=Category,y=2013]{\mydata};
\addplot table[x=Category,y=2014]{\mydata};
\addplot table[x=Category,y=2015]{\mydata};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Is `bar width=3pt` enough?

Comment: I think so, but now i'm getting this error
    Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `s' or `s@' (in '4pts'). 
    \end{axis}

Comment: Looks like you wrote `4pts` instead of `4pt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See how you think this looks. I used a colormap from the `colorbrewer` library. There are some comments in the code, but ask if anything is unclear.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\pgfplotsset{width=14cm,compat=1.9}
\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&]{
    Category&2007&2008&2009&2010&2011&2012&2013&2014&2015 \\
        CS  & 29 & 22   & 32   & 30   & 27  & 19 & 22 & 11 & 13 \\
        CRO & 20 & 11   & 14   & 23   & 17  & 14 & 9  & 9  & 8 \\
        NCO & 23 & 20   & 28   & 35   & 35  & 19 & 24 & 14 & 19 \\
        Ph  & 13 & 23   & 10   & 16   & 14  & 14 & 7  & 10 & 10 \\
        IS  & 52 & 32   & 38   & 34   & 40  & 28 & 34 & 22 & 29 \\
        L   & 8  & 21   & 11   & 14   & 6   & 6  & 10 & 10 & 8 \\
        NUK & 4  & 7    & 9    & 9    & 10  & 18 & 19 & 19 & 15\\
}\mydata


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ybar,
symbolic x coords={CS,CRO,NCO,Ph,IS,L,NUK},
xtick=data,
% reduce height of axis a bit
height=9cm,
% set width of bars
bar width=3pt,
% remove gap below bars
ymin=0,
% remove frame around legend, add some space
legend style={draw=none,column sep=2mm},
legend columns=2,
% customize how the legend images are drawn
% draw a square instead of two bars
legend image code/.code={%
       \draw[#1,draw=none,/tikz/.cd,yshift=-0.25em]
        (0cm,1pt) rectangle (6pt,7pt);},
% color map from colorbrewer
cycle list/Paired,
% the above only sets the color, need to specify that bars should be filled
every axis plot/.append style={fill}
]
\addplot table[x=Category,y=2007]{\mydata};
\addplot table[x=Category,y=2008]{\mydata};
\addplot table[x=Category,y=2009]{\mydata};
\addplot table[x=Category,y=2010]{\mydata};
\addplot table[x=Category,y=2011]{\mydata};
\addplot table[x=Category,y=2012]{\mydata};
\addplot table[x=Category,y=2013]{\mydata};
\addplot table[x=Category,y=2014]{\mydata};
\addplot table[x=Category,y=2015]{\mydata};

\legend{2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```